# Cloud BigTable stores multiple copies of same rowkey

Tags: go, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am writing to BigTable using the Go library. I use the `ApplyBulk` method to make multiple inserts atomically. However, when I query BigTable using the `ReadRows` function I see multiple copies/versions with the same row key.

For instance: In the below-mentioned example, I see multiple copies of the same RowKey with partial data and the last occurrence has all the columns with all the fields.

[image]

How can I ensure that only a single copy of data is stored for each row key? And how can I fetch only the latest version of rows inserted?

Code:

```
row_range := bigtable.PrefixRange("")

err = tbl.ReadRows(ctx,row_range, func(row bigtable.Row) bool {
// logic goes here
}, bigtable.RowFilter(bigtable.LatestNFilter(1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

As for as I know, that is normal. CBT stores the history of that row key and you'll want to pass a filter to get the latest one.

```golang
bigtable.RowFilter(bigtable.LatestNFilter(1))
```

**Update:** this is how I use that filter

```golang
    rowName := "myrow#key#id" 
    row, err := bt.Table.ReadRow(ctx, rowName, bigtable.RowFilter(bigtable.LatestNFilter(1)))
    if err != nil {
        // handle error...
    }
    if row == nil {
        // check for 0 result...
    }
```

**Update 2:**

Based on your code, using `ReadRows` instead, it looks like you're trying to get multiple row keys. so your code should pull the latest row for each of the row keys.

If you just want the one key that you show in your image then I would just use the `ReadRow` method instead.

```golang
err = tbl.ReadRow(ctx,"1564:u2Sng4xbtG", bigtable.RowFilter(bigtable.LatestNFilter(1)))
```

Else... I guess there could be an issue with how it was stored in CBT, but that is a little out of my skill set for CBT. hopefully, a CBT expert can chime in for you.

Comment: Despite using the LatestNFilter I do see multiple copies of the same rowkey. How can I ensure I fetch only the latest copy?

Comment: BigTable will return them all. The filter doesn't filter on BigTable's side, it filters on your side in the code. This is the normal behavior of CBT.  If that is not what you're seeing, then I think you need to post your code so we can get more context.  

There are ways to limit the selection using qualifiers and other row keys.  However, this gets really complex really fast.

Comment: Using the above-mentioned filter `bigtable.RowFilter(bigtable.LatestNFilter(1))` in my code to retrieve the last version of the record I still get the same result as the image posted in the question. I need a way of only fetching the last version for every row key

Comment: Again you're not showing your code on how you're using it. for example I would use that filter like this: 
```go 
 row, err := bt.Table.ReadRow(ctx, rowName, bigtable.RowFilter(bigtable.LatestNFilter(1)))
 if err != nil {
  // handle error...
 } 
```

Comment: ^ that didn't show up well, so I updated my post with how I would use it.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197522/discussion-between-dave-johnson-and-vasanti).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bit of confusion here:

1. Under no circumstances should ReadRows ever return **duplicate row keys**. Assuming that the rows in your spreadsheet correspond to the rows that the client library returned in func callback, then this is a bug in the client library. Please open an issue in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues and provide a way to reproduce the issue
2. Bigtable does allow **multiple versions of cell values**. It provides filters like  LatestNFilter() to hide old cell values and gc rules to remove them periodically. However, this is scoped to cell values and is unrelated to row keys. In other words, Bigtable provides cell versions not row versions.
3. ApplyBulk is not atomic and furthermore it doesn't provide any guarantees about  ordering of the mutations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is coming from the way that ApplyBulk transform the "insert tasks".

You can find more reference here https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable